# Rails set all record values to zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I set all records to 0 in a table?
-- UPDATE --
What I want to do is the following. I have a table called Pages with an attributed called position.
When I delete page from the table i want som function to reorder the positions, so that there wont be any not used positions.

EX. Position
1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 12
becomes
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here - what does your table look like? Are you trying to delete all of the rows from a table or change their values?

Comment: do you have to 0 all the values in a particular column or all values in all columns.

Comment: Mr. Matt please explain what you mean by "Worst pass"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pages.find(:all).sort_by(&:position).each_with_index do |page, index|
  page.position = index + 1
  page.save
end
```

Comment: This should be wrapped in a transaction or you will end up with duplicate positions when it runs in more than one process at once!

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question,

```
Pages.update_all(:position => 0)
```

One way to update the position array when a position is deleted is in a before_destroy callback.  This is reliable only if Rails' `destroy` method is the only way records are deleted!

```
def decrement_positions
  Pages.update_all('position = position - 1', ['position > ?', position])
end

before_destroy :decrement_positions
```

One race-condition free way to set all positions to adjacent values at once would be to drop into SQL:

```
Pages.update_all('position = 1 + (select count(1) from pages p where p.position < pages.position)')
```

Comment: Yo should to put 'Page' instead of 'Pages'. This way is better than make de 'each', because the database executes only one query.

Answer (score 0):

`Model.all.map { |m| m.field = 0 }.save!`

However this will create as many requests as records you have, so in case you have lots or records I'd suggest to use something like **[this](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [**acts_as_list**](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_list) plugin, it should deal with the renumbering of positions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would think using the plugin acts_as_list, like Andrew suggested, is a good idea if you need all the features, otherwise, I would just setup an after_destroy filter.

```
after_destroy :fix_order
def fix_order
  Page.order('position asc').all.each_with_index do |page, index|
    page.update_attribute(:position, index + 1) unless page.position == index + 1
  end
end
```